# Function that creates list from text field with given name in python

Tags: python, list, function

I need to create a function that creates a list from a named text file and can be given any name.

```
def createalist(filename,listname):
    with open(filename, mode="r") as myfile:
        listname=myfile.read().splitlines()
        myfile.close()
```

When I type 
`createalist("snames.txt",mynewlist)` or variants with brackets etc., I get  name `newarray` is not defined

Comment: You don't need to `close`

Comment: I don't see `newarray` in your code at all.

Comment: thanks I had the idea I could create a function that would create a list with any name I liked in this instance it would be called mynewlist. But obviously not possible

Comment: sorry that  should read mynewlist is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple misunderstanding of how variables work in Python.

What I am assuming you want to do is this:

```
def create_a_list(filename):
    with open(filename, mode="r") as my_file:
        my_list = my_file.read().splitlines()
        my_file.close()
        return my_list

anyName = create_a_list("snakes.txt")
```

The differences in my code versus yours is that I return the list and assign it to a variable rather than trying to pass a variable name/callback in.

When you want to give it any variable name, simply assign the variable equal to that function and make sure that the function returns the value you want the variable to have.